# Google Analytics nil error xcode swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, google-analytics

```
 func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {

    let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=id&forUsername=\(searchBar.text!.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "%20"))&key=1234")!)

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data, response, error) in

        if error == nil {
            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as! [String : AnyObject]

                if let items = json["items"] as? [String : AnyObject] {
                        if let id = items["id"] as? Int {
                            self.id = id
                    }
                }


                if let _ = json["error"] {
                    self.exists = false
                }

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    if self.exists{

                        print("\(self.id)")
                    }else {

                        self.exists = true

                    }
                }


            } catch let jsonError {
                print(jsonError.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

I want to get the Youtube channel **id** from google analytics but it keeps saying **"nil"**. I am not sure what i am doing wrong because everything works the same on my website! Please help! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I use your code, the JSON I get back is

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#channelListResponse",
 "etag": "\"m2yskBQFythfE4irbTIeOgYYfBU/uX-2P6nRpmv4I_ZWtiIyofqF5ss\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1,
  "resultsPerPage": 5
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#channel",
   "etag": "\"m2yskBQFythfE4irbTIeOgYYfBU/3W7RccGn0o-nTtgCGrEvd-AbX6Y\"",
   "id": "UCfpqR6vgT_mzWrbXcTYxL8w"
  }
 ]
}
```

So, `items["id"]` is not an Int.  Try

```
    if let id = items["id"] as? String
```

instead

Also, change `self.id` to a String.

UPDATED:

Also,

```
if let items = json["items"] as? [String : AnyObject] {
```

won't work because items is an array of dictionaries.

You need

```
if let items = json["items"] as? [[String : AnyObject]] {
```

and then,

```
if let id = items[0]["id"] as? String
```

You should probably check the items.count, but you can do that once you get this working.

Comment: I'm still getting "nil".

Comment: What is the first thing that is nil?  Is `json["items"] as? [String : AnyObject]` nil?

Comment: No the id is nil! The `print("\(self.id)")` is nill

Comment: By that time it could be nil for lots of reasons.  You need to check each step.  Put an else on every `if let` and tell me which `if let` statement goes to the else instead.

Comment: Ah, I see. items is an array, updating answer